# SSRS page splitting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

So I am performing a while loop on 3 stored procs and inserting the data into temp tables and then performing a union on them and when I run the query It returns 10 results but when I make a report out of it in SSRS it returns just the first result and stops! shouldn't it make multiple pages with the other results?

```
declare @temptable table  ( id int )

while (select count(*) from customerid c left join @temptable t on c.id = t.id where t.id is null) > 0 begin

insert into @temptable select min(c.id)  from customerid c  left join @temptable t on c.id = t.id  where t.id is null

declare @id2 varchar(50) = (select max(id) from @temptable)

-- insert into temp tables here  
   exec DoctorsSDJs @id = @id2 
-- insert into temp table  
   exec LocationSDJs @id = @id2 
-- insert into temp tables  
   exec PatientSDJs @id = @id2

-- performing my union on the 3 tables

end
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are using in the dataset for SSRS?  When you say in SSRS, do you mean the Report Builder or Visual Studio or via the Report Manager?

Comment: do you mean 10 resultsets or 10 records in a resultset. If the first option, SSRS only sees the first resultsset as far as I know.

Comment: @jesse I just added a query showing what I am doing. and this is right in visual studios

Comment: @AlanSchofield yeah I meant 10 result sets if that's the case then yeah ill have to figure out some work around

Comment: Performing union outside loop. Using group in SSRS to split it to 10 pages.